# DB design - FK for 1:1 tables

Tags: database-design

I have 2 tables, both relate to eachother as 1:1 -> Country and National_Anthem.
Both are in separate tables because I need to store their own metadata.

Now does the FK of Country go in the National_Anthem table OR does the FK of National_Anthem go in the Country table? Since this is 1:1, i guess it can work eitherway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems subjective, but I would put the link to the country in the anthem table, because I think a national anthem is sort of defined by its country, rather than the other way around.  Also a country will have many properties similar to its national anthem (official language for example), and it would be impractical to have all of them reflected in a single table.

Comment: Further to this, it all depends on the context.  Is your system more about Countries or mostly about Anthems?  If your only two tables are Country and Anthem, then you have a very small system and you might as well just make one table.

Answer (score 1):

The basic 1:1 would be:

[image]

However, national anthems may change, so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @John Zwinck it's subjective, and I would do it the other way around.
Because a National Anthem kind of "belongs" to a country, and if I had a class for each, probably the Country class would have had a NationalAnthem as a property (and so this should be reflected in the DB). But I can't say that's the absolute right answer, and @John has much sense in what he's saying.